# Error in friedman.test.default(c(3.7005, 1.3212, 2.0572, 1.8833, 0.4539, : not an unreplicated complete block design

Tags: r, friedman-test, error-message

I have a [non-parametric data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JkYFLQc5BBXlFYZT-Fc4o-xkHhwUkjEP/view?usp=sharing) and would like to run Friedman Test.
Here is my code:

```
res <- data_copy %>% friedman_test( ten ~  res | order)
res
```

However, I got the error as follow:

```
Error in friedman.test.default(c(3.7005, 1.3212, 2.0572, 1.8833, 
0.4539,  : 
not an unreplicated complete block design
```

How to fix the error?